# Linq to Entities - left Outer Join

Tags: linq-to-entities

Could you please help me to figure this one out?
I need to replace a join with OSLP table with OUTER join. Seems a bit tricky for someone who is not an expert in Linq to entities. How would I do that?

```
var surgeonList = (
    from item in context.T1_STM_Surgeon
        .Include("T1_STM_SurgeonTitle")
        .Include("OTER")
    where item.ID == surgeonId
    join reptable in context.OSLP 
        on item.Rep equals reptable.SlpCode
    select new
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        First = item.First,
        Last = item.Last,
        Rep = reptable.SlpName,
        Reg = item.OTER.descript,
        PrimClinic = item.T1_STM_ClinicalCenter.Name,
        Titles = item.T1_STM_SurgeonTitle,
        Phone = item.Phone,
        Email = item.Email,
        Address1 = item.Address1,
        Address2 = item.Address2,
        City = item.City,
        State = item.State,
        Zip = item.Zip,
        Comments = item.Comments,
        Active = item.Active,
        DateEntered = item.DateEntered
    }).ToList();
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is as follows and let me know if you have trouble translating your code.
Generic Outer Join (group join):

var query =
        from l in left

```
    join r in right
    on l.ID
    equals l.right.ID into groupedJoin
    select new
    {
        ID= l.ID,
        OuterJoined= groupedJoin.Select(r=> right)
    };
```

Your result is everything in left even if right doesn't exist.

Obviously i can't guarantee it will compile but it would look like this:

var surgeonList = (

```
   from item in context.T1_STM_Surgeon
      .Include("T1_STM_SurgeonTitle")
      .Include("OTER")
  where item.ID == surgeonId
  join reptable in context.OSLP 
      on item.Rep equals reptable.SlpCode into groupedJoin
  select new
  {
      ID = item.ID,
      First = item.First,
      Last = item.Last,
      Rep = reptable.SlpName,
      Reg = item.OTER.descript,
      PrimClinic = item.T1_STM_ClinicalCenter.Name,
      Titles = item.T1_STM_SurgeonTitle,
      Phone = item.Phone,
      Email = item.Email,
      Address1 = item.Address1,
      Address2 = item.Address2,
      City = item.City,
      State = item.State,
      Zip = item.Zip,
      Comments = item.Comments,
      Active = item.Active,
      DateEntered = item.DateEntered
      OSLP  = groupedJoin.Select(x=>WHATEVERYOUNEED)
}).ToList();
```

And you just need to replace  groupedJoin.Select(x=>WHATEVERYOUNEED) with either selecting something or a simple .ToList

Comment: Could you edit your post to include code-blocks, please? It's impossible to read.

Comment: I did shortly after i saw the chaos... is that better?